# Android: Cast SDK v3 Crashing in Release build only

Tags: android, google-cast

Whenever I try to run a release build of my app, I immediately get a crash when attempting to use any of the Google Cast features

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialize CastContext.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<editpackagename.utils.CastOptionsProvider> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext>
                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.zzbd(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at editpackagename.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
```

That crash happens as soon as I call this in MainActivity:

```
CastContext castContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);
```

If I run a debug build, everything works as expected. Using Play Services cast-framework 9.4.0.

Comment: I have gone over the documentation and added the CastOptionsProvider and set it up with the com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME meta-data

Comment: And for production build I had to add this line to my proguard file to get it work. `-keep class abc.xyz.videocast.CastOptionsProvider { *; }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Made CastOptionsProvider public, and that seems to have taken care of it. Not sure if it's because the class is in a subpackage or not, but looks fine. Documentation doesn't have any access modifiers.

Comment: This did it it for me, I was having the exact same problem.